# How to make MSBuild sign all files in a Clickonce application

Tags: c#, clickonce, sha

I have an application (WPF) installed by Clickonce and now I need to sign it, so Windows can recognize my company as a trusted issuer. The following command line was used in my C.I. tool (parameters with diamonds <> are used only to exemplify the situation):

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe /target:clean;build;publish /p:ApplicationVersion=<VERSION> /p:SignAssembly=true /p:GenerateManifests=true /p:SignManifests=true /p:AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile=<PFX_PATH> /p:ManifestCertificateThumbprint=<CERTIFICATE_ID> /property:Configuration=<CONFIGURATION>;PublishDir=<PUBLISH_DIR>;BootstrapperEnabled=true;PublishUrl=<PUBLISH_URL>;InstallUrl=<INSTALL_URL>;UpdateUrl=<UPDATE_URL> C:\hudson\slave\workspace\NIMBUS-NFE-NFEasy2\NFeasy2\NFeasy2.sln
```

The problem is: only the setup.exe is signed, and only with SHA-256 algorithm. Thus, when the user run my application, the issuer is not recognized. Also, when running with Windows XP, the setup will never run because the SO doesn't recognize the signature (it seems that WinXP needs SHA-1).

How can I setup my project or command line to sign all files with both SHA-1 and SHA-256 algorithms? Also, will this stop prompting user's permission every time the application is run? If not, is there a way to do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading a lot of solutions through the Internet, I managed to write a batch file to do the full signing. Note that this works only with specific versions, and I had to put them in my Path in the following order:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86;

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin;
```

The script is the following:

```
rem renaming the setup.exe because it will be treated separately
ren setup.exe setup._

rem removing the .DEPLOY extension, getting back the original one
for /r %%x in (*.deploy) do ren "%%x" *.

rem signing all files with my certificate
for /r %%x in (*.exe *.dll) do signtool.exe sign /fd sha1 /as /sha1 <MY_CERTIFICATE> "%%x"
for /r %%x in (*.exe *.dll) do signtool.exe sign /fd sha256 /as /sha1 <MY_CERTIFICATE> "%%x"

rem updating the manifest with the new signatures
for /r %%x in (*.manifest) do mage.exe -update "%%x"

rem signing the manifest file
for /r %%x in (*.manifest) do mage.exe -sign "%%x" -ch <MY_CERTIFICATE>

rem putting the .DEPLOY extension in all files renamed previously
for /r %%x in (*.exe *.dll *.config *.cer *.ttf *.ico *.xml *.p7b) do ren "%%x" *.*.deploy

rem getting back setup.exe
ren setup._ setup.exe 

rem signing setup.exe file
signtool.exe sign /fd sha1 /as /sha1 <MY_CERTIFICATE> setup.exe
signtool.exe sign /fd sha256 /as /sha1 <MY_CERTIFICATE> setup.exe

rem updating MyApp.Application file
for /r %%x in (*.manifest) do mage.exe -update MyApp.Application -appm "%%x"

rem signing MyApp.Application file
mage.exe -sign MyApp.Application -ch <MY_CERTIFICATE>

rem updating the new signed file to the destiny folder
for /r %%x in (*.application) do xcopy MyApp.Application "%%x" /y
```

Comment: I honestly cannot believe this worked. Thank you. Beautiful piece of work.

Comment: This is not working for me, I'm trying to sign a vsto click once application and I'm getting "Reference in the deployment does not match the identity defined in the application manifest." after running this script. Any suggestions on resolving this?

Comment: I take it back - this does work. If it is a VSTO this is what the last 3 commands look like (Sorry new lines don't work in comments):

rem updating MyPlugin.vsto file
for /r %%x in (*.manifest) do mage.exe -update MyPlugin.vsto -appm "%%x"

rem signing MyPlugin.vsto file
mage.exe -sign MyPlugin.vsto -ch <MY_CERTIFICATE>

rem updating the new signed file to the destination folder
for /r %%x in (*.vsto) do xcopy MyPlugin.vsto "%%x" /y